# Convert String Count into a Calculated Field

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to turn a count of strings into a calculated field, but I am not able to use the drop down menu in the calculated field.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the drop down you are attempting to access? I am not aware of a drop down in the calculated field window except where searching through the function types.

Comment: What is your expected output here? Do you want to change the data type of the Count measure?

Comment: For using a Dimension as an aggregate, convert it to a Measure by dragging or using the drop down menu. This can then be used in creating a calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you are trying to do here.

If you are trying to count the number of unique membership IDs then you need to write a formula like `CountD(Member ID)`. You will then have a measure that gives the total number of member IDs in the database.

If , on the other hand, you want to count the number of times a member appears in the database, you could use `Count(Member ID)`. Then, when you drag the Member ID to a row, you can drag the new measure you have creates and get a table of the counts for each member.

Comment: Thank you, the first part is exactly what I was looking for.